# AndroidManifest.xml doesn't exist or has incorrect root tag for React Native

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native

I can't even setup react native. it's showing this error

[image: I can't even setup react native. it's showing this error]

Answer (score 10):

You've opened Android Studio in the wrong folder, you need to open the `android` folder rather than the projects `root` folder in Android Studio.

#### How to open an Android project correctly in Android Studio

When you open Android Studio, select `Open an existing Android Studio project`
[image: android studio]

Navigate to the `android` folder inside your project's `root` directory, select the folder named `android` and then click open.

Here my app is called `NewApp` so I navigate to that folder and then find the `android` folder.

[image: folder selection]

You should then see something like this:

[image: android studio]

Answer (score 3):

The right way to open android project is to open project level `build.gradle` file when open from android studio (Just browse and double tab `build.gradle` file) for normal and react-native project both.
Please see the selected file in screenshot for reference.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I found it incredibly hard to find this simple instruction to open a project. I've spent two days trying to open a project.